# Proving cancellation laws

Tags: linear-algebra

For arbitrary elements a, b, and c in a field, the following statements are true.
(a) Ifa+b=c+b,then a=c.

My proof for (a) is since a,b and c are elements in a field, there exists a -b such that b+(-b)=0. So a+b+(-b)=c+b+(-b) is a=c. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. That is right. You can also see this as follows:
\begin{align}
a &= a+0 \\
&= a+(b+(-b)) \\
&= (a+b)+(-b) \\
&= (c+b)+(-b) \qquad \textrm{since $a+b=c+b$} \\
&= c+(b+(-b)) \\
&= c+0 \\
&= c
\end{align}